# determine page goal and page cost

Tags: page-breaking, badness

I want to find possible page break problems automatically. I've read the TeXBook on the page breaking algorithm and think what I want to do is output to the log the `pagegoal`-`pagetotal` and the cost. I see the equation to compute the cost but is it already available in a counter or dimen?

My hope is that I can output these parameters for every page and use a script to find problematic pages that need to be dealt with by a human.

I see that there are dimens for `pagegoal` and `pagetotal`, but I can't find where the value for cost is kept.

Hoping to use the `everypage` or `everyshi` package to write the parameters to the log. I can imagine that the timing of knowing the page cost at shipout time may be impossible.

Anyone know how I can find the cost and print it out for each page?

Comment: if you put \tracingpages=1 the page break costs are logged (might take a bit of parsing to fish out the information you need but it should all be there)

Comment: You're right I think--I'll start working on the parsing now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put `\tracingpages=1` the page break costs are logged (might take a bit of parsing to fish out the information you need but it should all be there)